# pgfplots cycle list and thickness

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting a graph for which I want to cycle through some colors to plot the curves. I defined a custom color list from a custom color map and managed to apply it to my graph.

However, I want to plot the curves as `very thick` but it cannot be passed as an optional parameter to `\addplot`. I tried to pass the argument `very thick` to the whole axis (see the MWE) but the axis itself also becomes very thick which I do not want.

How to pass a thickness argument to the custom defined cycle to apply it to the curves only?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % To produce graphs within tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \pgfplotsset{colormap={CM}{color=(blue) color=(orange) color=(red)}}
        
        \begin{axis}[colormap name=CM,
            cycle list={[samples of colormap={5}]},
            very thick
            ]
            
            \addplot coordinates{(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
            \addplot coordinates{(0,2) (0.5,2) (1,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(0,3) (0.5,3) (1,3)};
            \addplot coordinates{(0,4) (0.5,4) (1,4)};
            \addplot coordinates{(0,5) (0.5,5) (1,5)};

        \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* add `very thick` to `\addplot`, if you do

```
\addplot +[very thick] ...`
```

The `+` means that the options in the brackets are appended to those from the active cycle list.

A simpler way of adding the option to all `\addplot`s in an axis, is to add

```
every axis plot/.append style={very thick}
```

to the `axis` options.